# Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: ''windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

This is occurring on my .NET Core 2.2 web server.

I'm getting this exception when trying to read anything from a MySql database. I shouldn't be using windows-1252 anywhere, I've verified there's no references in my code, I should be using UTF-8 everywhere. Here is the code that causes the exception:

```
        public async Task<AdminCredentials> Authenticate(string partnerId, string productInstanceId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partnerId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(productInstanceId))
            {
                return null;
            }

            AdminCredentials item = null;

            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = $@"
                    SELECT partner_id, product_instance_id
                    FROM integrations
                    WHERE partner_id = @partnerId AND product_instance_id = @productInstanceId;";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnerId", partnerId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productInstanceId", productInstanceId);
                using (var reader = await _db.ExecuteReaderAsync(cmd))
```

Happens on `using (var reader = await _db.ExecuteReaderAsync(cmd))`. The full exception message is:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: ''windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'
   at System.Text.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
```

I've done a ton of digging but no luck so far. This is happening with every read request of the database, not just this one. The database is utf-8 encoded as well.

Everything seems to work fine from a front-end users perspective. Just this exception occurring literally every time.

Comment: Try switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/
Not only is it fully UTF-8 by default (shouldn't ever use `windows-1252`), it actually implements async methods properly (so `ExecuteReaderAsync` will work as you expect).

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the database, try to perform the "set names utf8" query before "select ..."